# Python brute force for a function of 2 variables

Tags: python, scipy

I have the following function:

```
((sin(((x-8)**2+y**2)**0.5))/((((x-8)**2+y**2)**0.5)))+0.8*((sin(((x+8)**2+y**2)**0.5))/(((x+8)**2+y**2)**0.5))
```

I want to find the global maxima and minima of this function using brute force approach in Python. I have looked on scipy.optimize.brute but I am not sure on how to do the same for a function of 2 variables.

```
   y = np.linspace(-20,20,1000)
x = np.linspace(-20,20,1000)
def f(x,y):
    return (((sin(((x-8)**2+y**2)**0.5))/((((x-8)**2+y**2)**0.5)))+0.8*((sin(((x+8)**2+y**2)**0.5))/(((x+8)**2+y**2)**0.5)))
rranges = (slice(-4, 4, 0.25), slice(-4, 4, 0.25))
val  = scipy.optimize.brute(f, rranges, finish=optimize.fmin)
```

This is my code so far. It gives an error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Aravind_Sampathkumar/Desktop/PY/Bruteforce.py", line 11, in <module>
    val  = scipy.optimize.brute(f, rranges, finish=optimize.fmin)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py", line 2825, in brute
    Jout = vecfunc(*grid)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 2755, in __call__
    return self._vectorize_call(func=func, args=vargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 2834, in _vectorize_call
    res = array(outputs, copy=False, subok=True, dtype=otypes[0])
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Not sure what scipy does, but brute forcing is conceptually super easy: compute all values on a grid and pick the highest (lowest). Optionally refine with a non brute force routine starting at these points.

Comment: What you have is not a function it misses the `f(...) =` part. The function `f` in your code has an argument `z` but it is not used.

Comment: I had initially kept x,y=z inside the function which i saw in the docs for scipy.

Comment: Just not sure on how to call f in the .optimize.brute call if I declare f as f(x,y)

Comment: It might be a typo but the equation you defined is actually the opposite of the equation in your code.

Comment: Oh yeah my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the scipy documentation:

> scipy.optimize.brute(func, ranges, args=(), Ns=20, full_output=0, finish=, disp=False)
>
> func : callable
>
> The objective function to be minimized. Must be in the form f(x,
>   *args), where x is the argument in the form of a 1-D array and args is a tuple of any additional fixed parameters needed to completely
>   specify the function.
>
> ranges : tuple
>
> Each component of the ranges tuple must be either a “slice object” or
>   a range tuple of the form (low, high). The program uses these to
>   create the grid of points on which the objective function will be
>   computed. See Note 2 for more detail.

In your case, you should specify what are the variables to in your function as a 1D array. It should look like this in your case:

```
from math import sin
from scipy import optimize

# There's no parameter here, just like in your code
def f(z):
    x,y=z
    return (-((sin(((x-8)**2+y**2)**0.5))/((((x-8)**2+y**2)**0.5)))+0.8*((sin(((x+8)**2+y**2)**0.5))/(((x+8)**2+y**2)**0.5)))

# 
rranges = (slice(-20, 20, 0.2), slice(-20, 20, 0.2))

resbrute = optimize.brute(f, rranges, full_output=True, finish=optimize.fmin)
```

Note that I've changed your `rranges` from `np.linspace` to `slice`. While `np.linspace` arguments are `(start, stop, nb_samples)`, `slice` arguments are `(start, stop, step)`. Please be aware that **they don't do the same thing.** If the number of steps isn't important to you, a simplification is possible:

```
# Simply indicate lower_bound and upper_bound for each variable
resbrute = optimize.brute(f,((-20,20),(-20,20)))
```

To obtain your global minimum, give a look at `val[0]`. It should be a tuple containing the optimized value of `x` and `y`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That works. So z represents x and y as a 1D array right?Also this gives me the global minimum. how do you find the global maximum?

Comment: val[1] gives me the value of the function at the global minima right?

Comment: Yes, `z` is a 1-D array that represents `(x,y)`. I can't remember of a maximize function, but I guess that working on `-f` instead of `f` should do the trick.

Comment: -f as in just change f to -f inside the .brute function call? ok that doesn't work. Maybe If i return the negative of the function

Comment: You guessed right. `val[1]` is the minimum value of your function.
You need to add the `-` in the equation of your function. In your `brute` call, `f` is just the name of your function, not its equation. Your idea may work but I'm not sure. Try it out!

Comment: It does return the max value but with a negative sign. Not sure if i can consider that the max value.

Comment: I tried running your code again and here are my results.

With the equation in my answer and `resbrute = optimize.brute(f,((-20,20),(-20,20)))`, I have a minimum of `resbrute[1] = -1.0175023482171592`.

If I add a `-` right before `(-((sin(((x-8) ...` and the same `resbrute`, I have a minimum of `-0.8238396168538561`, which means that your function's maximum is `0.8238396168538561`. 

Where did you put the minus sign ?

Comment: I placed the sign at the same place as you did but my maximum value is at -0.989 or 0.989 and the minimum value is at -0.280.

Comment: In that case 0.989 is your maximum value.
If you still doubt that this is the maximum try plotting your function and plot the coordonates that result in 0.989 :)